# Ubuntu servers can't be reached

Tags: apt, server

First question on AskUbuntu, so please excuse my lack of knowledge and any mistakes I could make.
I have a **Ubuntu 19.10 server** to which I connect through SSH. I wanted to install a package through APT, and it kept waiting for headers. I tried updating, it failed. When I rebooted, the changelog failed. ("Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings")

However, it still has an internet connection (the apache2 server it hosts can still be reached, I can still connect through SSH&FTP).

When I try https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release in my browser, it works well.

Is Ubuntu down? Is there a problem with my server?

Thanks in advance,
Mehdi

Comment: Can your server ping the target?

Comment: @user535733 Yep, it can ping changelogs.ubuntu.com (one of the URLs that failed to load)

Comment: Try the install again.

Comment: @user535733 Still doesn't work.

Comment: have  you made any changes in the networking? are you running a static IP on your local network or DHCP from the router

Comment: Is your server behind some kind of procy? Or on some corporate/school network?

Comment: @user535733 No, no proxy/corporate network.

Comment: @JohnOrion No changes.

Note: It used to work, however, it stopped working.